# Linear PDE with variable coefficients method of solution?

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I am trying to solve the following PDE and have experienced some difficulty.

$x^2u_x - xyu_y = -y^2$

I have divided both sides by $x^2$ to get the following:

$u_x - (\frac{y}{x})u_y = -(\frac{y}{x})^2$

This looks awfully similar to the first order linear ODEs that require an integrating factor. Would it be inappropriate to add $v = (\frac{y}{x})$ as a substitution to solve the equation?

Comment: Have you tried the method of characteristics?

Comment: @TonyS.F.

I have, but I hit a road block in finding the second linearly independent equation relative to $du$.

Comment: Tne answer is here :  http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1747446/method-of-characteristics-for-pdes-yielding-different-answer-than-expected-can/1747744#1747744