# Method of Characteristics for PDEs Yielding Different Answer Than Expected? (Can I get a check on work?)

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I was interested in solving the following system:

$x^2u_x - xyu_y = -y^2$

I used the method of characteristics to reduce my problem into the following:

$\left(\frac{dx}{x^2}\right)$ = $\left(\frac{dy}{-xy}\right)$ = $\left(\frac{du}{-y^2}\right)$

I looped the $dy$ and $dx$ terms together to get a solution defined by $F(xy)$, and I need to find the $u(x,y)$ solution.

I went about targeting $\left(\frac{dy}{-xy}\right)$ and $\left(\frac{du}{-y^2}\right)$

I rearranged the differentials to get $\left(\frac{du}{dy}\right)$ = $\left(\frac{y}{x}\right)$

Integrating both sides yielded $u(x,y) = \left(\frac{y^2}{2x}\right)$

$u_x = \left(\frac{-y^2}{2x^2}\right)$

$u_y = \left(\frac{y}{x}\right)$

Now, checking my solution:

$x^2\left(\frac{-y^2}{2x^2}\right) - xy\left(\frac{y}{x}\right) = -y^2$

= $\left(\frac{-y^2}{2}\right) - y^2 \neq -y^2$

The real solution is $\left(\frac{y^2}{3x}\right)$, which I don't get how I could get that with the method of characteristics. Sure, it works when I check it, but I want to know where it came from.

What went wrong?

Comment: You cannot integrate both sides of $\frac{du}{dy}=\frac{y}{x}$ because $\frac{y}{x}$ is not function of $y$ alone. To integrate correctly, you have to express the two terms of the equation on the form of TOTAL derivatives. This is the "breadcrumb trail" to find the solution.

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac{dx}{x^2}=\frac{dy}{-xy}=\frac{du}{-y^2}$$
First characteristic equation , from $\frac{dx}{x^2}=\frac{dy}{-xy}\quad\to\quad \frac{dx}{x}+\frac{dy}{y}=0$
$$xy=c_1$$
Second characteristic equation, from  : $\frac{-y^3 dx}{x^2 y}=\frac{2x y^2dy}{2x^2y}=du$

Using the identity : $\frac{a}{b}=\frac{c}{d}=\frac{a+c}{b+d}$

$$\frac{-y^3 dx}{x^2 y}=\frac{2x y^2dy}{2x^2y}=\frac{-y^3 dx+2x y^2dy}{x^2y+2x^2y}=\frac{-y^3 dx+2x y^2dy}{3x^2y}$$
$$\frac{-y^3 dx+2x y^2dy}{3x^2y}=du$$
This is the total derivative of $\frac{y^2}{3x}$, thus the second characteristic equation is :
$$u-\frac{y^2}{3x}=c_2$$
The general solution of the PDE expressed on implicit form is :
$$\Phi\left(xy\:,\:u-\frac{y^2}{3x}\right)=0$$
where $\Phi$ is any differentiable function of two variables.

This equation can be solved for $u$ leading to the explicit form :
$$u(x,y)=\frac{y^2}{3x}+F(xy)$$
where $F$ is any differentiable function of one variable.